# Add new value of key at python dict. jsom from another file

Tags: python, dictionary

Good day! I have question about python dictionary and json! At one file i am creating json dictionary with this structure:

```
{"face_1": {"face_rect": "(127, 68, 177, 177)", "Age": 1, "Gender": 1}}
```

For it  use this code (i - number of faces, (x,y,w,h) - rect. of coord.):

```
for i, (x, y, w, h) in enumerate(faces):
        face = dict()
        face["face_{}".format(i + 1)] =  {"face_rect": str((x, y, w, h)), "Age": 1, "Gender": 1}
        with open('face.json', 'a') as fp:
            data_to_write = json.dumps(face)
            fp.write(data_to_write + '\n')
```

Before this part all is great. My question - how i can open this dictionary (face.json) at the another py file and CHANGE value of 'Age', 'Gender' and save it? 
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Suggest using `json.load` as you already know `json.dumps` - maybe even directly use `json.dump` with the file as target? B.t.w. as you only use `i` as `i + 1` once in your code, maybe consider using `... enumerate(faces, start=1):` right from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) in order to load the dictionary:

```
with open('face.json') as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)

# Make some modifications here.
```

Then you can save the data again using [`json.dump`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump):

```
with open('face.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(data, fp)
```

Note that there is no need to invoke `fp.write` manually as `json.dump` handles this already for you. Also when opening the file you want to use mode `'w'` instead of `'a'` because otherwise you don't overwrite the old data but instead just append the new dictionary to the end. This will also invalidate the json format.